# GPO company-wide for Wi-Fi adapter settings : 5ghz band

Tags: gpo

I am trying to set GPO company-wide for Wi-Fi , adapter settings:
property: preferred band
Value :3. Prefer 5GHz band.
Any advise would be much apprecited
Thanks
M

Answer (score 0):

I was curious if you found a solution to this?  I'm interested in doing the same thing.  I'd like to set it so the computers prefer 5Ghz, but are able to fall back to 2.4GHz if needed.

Eric